# Subtract n hours from a DateTime in Ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime, subtraction, hour

I have a Ruby DateTime which gets filled from a form. Additionally I have n hours from the form as well. I'd like to subtract those n hours from the previous DateTime. (To get a time range).

DateTime has two methods "-" and "<<" to subtract day and month, but not hour. ([API](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html)). Any suggestions how I can do that?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You could do this.

```
adjusted_datetime = (datetime_from_form.to_time - n.hours).to_datetime
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works in a Rails context.  The hours() method comes from one of the date helpers in Rails not from the Ruby standard lib.

Comment: This solution needs `require "active_support/all"` (or simply `rails`).

Answer (score 42):

You can just subtract less than one whole day:

```
two_hours_ago = DateTime.now - (2/24.0)
```

This works for minutes and anything else too:

```
hours = 10
minutes = 5
seconds = 64

hours = DateTime.now - (hours/24.0) #<DateTime: 2015-03-11T07:27:17+02:00 ((2457093j,19637s,608393383n),+7200s,2299161j)>
minutes = DateTime.now - (minutes/1440.0) #<DateTime: 2015-03-11T17:22:17+02:00 ((2457093j,55337s,614303598n),+7200s,2299161j)>
seconds = DateTime.now - (seconds/86400.0) #<DateTime: 2015-03-11T17:26:14+02:00 ((2457093j,55574s,785701811n),+7200s,2299161j)>
```

If floating point arithmetic inaccuracies are a problem, you can use `Rational` or some other safe arithmetic utility.

Comment: Beware, this leads to unexpected results because of floating point arithmetic inaccuracies...

Comment: In that case Rational class is a solution ^^

Answer (score 22):

The advance method is nice if you want to be more explicit about behavior like this.

```
adjusted = time_from_form.advance(:hours => -n)
```

Comment: For anyone who tries this: it's not in the stdlib, it's provided by ActiveSupport.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617284/where-is-time-advance-documented.

Comment: Thanks jkp. I was getting frustrated at all these examples not working in plain ole irb.

Answer (score 20):

You just need to take off fractions of a day.

```
two_hours_ago = DateTime.now - (2.0/24)
```

- 1.0 = one day
- 1.0/24 = 1 hour
- 1.0/(24*60) = 1 minute
- 1.0/(24*60*60) = 1 second

Comment: I'm not sure how you would handle "leap seconds"

Answer (score 12):

`n/24.0` trick won't work properly as floats are eventually rounded:

```
>> DateTime.parse('2009-06-04 02:00:00').step(DateTime.parse('2009-06-04 05:00:00'),1.0/24){|d| puts d}
2009-06-04T02:00:00+00:00
2009-06-04T03:00:00+00:00
2009-06-04T03:59:59+00:00
2009-06-04T04:59:59+00:00
```

You can, however, use Rational class instead:

```
>> DateTime.parse('2009-06-04 02:00:00').step(DateTime.parse('2009-06-04 05:00:00'),Rational(1,24)){|d| puts d}
2009-06-04T02:00:00+00:00
2009-06-04T03:00:00+00:00
2009-06-04T04:00:00+00:00
2009-06-04T05:00:00+00:00
```

Comment: I meant: I believe "step" is not core Ruby.  However, you can the Rational strategy with straight subtraction as in some other answers.

Comment: 1) `step` was there just to illustrate the point 2) `step` is in standard lib: http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/date/1.9.3/Date:step

Comment: +1 as this is probably the one and only correct way of performing date arithmetic on DateTime objects.

Answer (score 8):

If you are working in *Rails*, the following super-intutive possibility exists:

```
> Time.now - 12.hours
=> 2019-08-19 05:50:43 +0200
```

(This also works with *seconds*, *minutes*, *days*, and *years*)

if you're using just Ruby, `DateTime` can't do this, but `Time` can:

```
t = Time.now
t = t - (hours*60**2)
```

Note that `Time` also stores date information, it's all a little strange.

If you have to work with `DateTime`

```
DateTime.commercial(date.year,date.month,date.day,date.hour-x,date.minute,date.second)
```

might work, but is ugly. The doc says `DateTime` is immutable, so I'm not even sure about `-` and `<<`

Comment: Yes, "DateTime objects are immutable once created." - it's like the String class in Java. Nevertheless: **method "-":** "If x is a Numeric value, create a new Date object that is x days earlier than the current one.", so we could work with that. I thought about your idea, too but I'm not sure how ruby converts a negative value from "hour-x". Is that what makes it ugly for you? Well, I try it out. Let's see what the DateTime class does ;)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `t = t-hours*60*60`?

Comment: Thx, fixed (and updated with the most elegant possibility that now exists.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't say what use you need to make of the value you get, but what about just dividing your hours by 24 so you're subtracting a fraction of a day?

```
mydatetime = DateTime.parse(formvalue)
nhoursbefore = mydatetime - n / 24.0
```

Answer (score 5):

If I'm allowed to use `Time` instead of `DateTime` (There are [several ways to translate one to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279769/convert-to-from-datetime-and-time-in-ruby/280026#280026)):

```
# Just remove the number of seconds from the Time object
Time.now - (6 * 60 * 60) # 6 hours ago
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238878/is-it-acceptable-practice-to-patch-rubys-base-classes-such-as-fixnum) before you decide to use the approach I've outlined here. It seems it may not be best practice to modify the behavior of a base class in Ruby (which I can understand). So, take this answer with a grain of salt...

---

[MattW's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238684/subtract-n-hours-from-a-datetime-in-ruby#238690) was the first thing I thought of, but I also didn't like it very much.

I suppose you could make it less ugly by patching `DateTime` and `Fixnum` to do what you want:

```
require 'date'

# A placeholder class for holding a set number of hours.
# Used so we can know when to change the behavior
# of DateTime#-() by recognizing when hours are explicitly passed in.

class Hours
   attr_reader :value

   def initialize(value)
      @value = value
   end
end

# Patch the #-() method to handle subtracting hours
# in addition to what it normally does

class DateTime

   alias old_subtract -

   def -(x) 
      case x
        when Hours; return DateTime.new(year, month, day, hour-x.value, min, sec)
        else;       return self.old_subtract(x)
      end
   end

end

# Add an #hours attribute to Fixnum that returns an Hours object. 
# This is for syntactic sugar, allowing you to write "someDate - 4.hours" for example

class Fixnum
   def hours
      Hours.new(self)
   end
end
```

Then you can write your code like this:

```
some_date = some_date - n.hours
```

where `n` is the number of hours you want to substract from `some_date`

Comment: This is a complete solution.  I don't know if the question actually asked about it or if he didn't had discovered that the new operator is
"Negative values of h, min, and sec are treating as counting backwards from the end of the next larger unit "

Answer (score 2):

I like using the helpers in active_support. It makes it really clean and easy to read.

See the example below:

```
require 'active_support'

last_accessed = 2.hours.ago
last_accessed = 2.weeks.ago
last_accessed = 1.days.ago
```

There might be a way to use that kind of syntax to do what you are looking for, if the current date is used.

Answer (score -3):

You can use this :

```
Time.now.ago(n*60*60)
```

For example `Time.now.ago(7200)` will give the date and time that was before 2 hours from now.

Comment: This question is about Ruby, not Ruby on Rails.