# Alternatives to monkey patching core classes

Tags: ruby, oop, monkeypatching

I am still new to Ruby and basically just writing my first micro-program after finishing Cooper's book. I was pointed to the direction of avoiding monkey patching but the problem is I don't know what are the alternatives to achieve the same behavior.
Basically, I want to add a new method that is accessible by every string object. The obvious monkey-patching way is to:

```
class String
  def do_magic
    ...magic...
  end
end
```

I recall there's a way using String.send. But I can't remember how it's done nor where I read it.
Can anyone point out any alternatives that would still let me make that method available to the String class and child objects?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Any other way of doing this would just be a more awkward syntax for monkey patching. There are ways involving `send` and `eval` and all sorts of things, but *why*? Go ahead and do it the obvious way.

You want to be careful of monkey patching in big projects or when you have dependencies, because you can wind up with conflicts when several hands are all messing around in the same place. This doesn't mean look for an alternative syntax that accomplishes the same thing — it means be careful when you're making changes that could affect code that's not yours. This probably isn't a concern in your particular case. It's just something that might need to be addressed in larger projects.

One alternative in Ruby is that you can add methods to a single object.

```
a = "Hello"
b = "Goodbye"
class <<a
  def to_slang
    "yo"
  end
end
a.to_slang # => "yo"
b.to_slang # NoMethodError: undefined method `to_slang' for "Goodbye":String
```

Comment: I can see how it really depends on the situation and the nature of the project itself. And I think this would also apply to all of the do/don't pairs.
Considering my particular case, yes, it makes sense that it should not hurt. After all, I am adding a new method. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Monkey patching is a slippery slope, at best.  It might seem elegant for small teams on closed-source projects, but you never know when your source code might be packaged as a gem or otherwise copied by someone down the line, and if they want their String to do_magic in a slightly different way, then one monkey patched method will overwrite the other, and no warning will be thrown.  It is a recipe for hard-to-find bugs.  It's especially problematic if you are overwriting methods of base classes included with Ruby.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to add a new method that is accessible to every string object, then doing it the way you have it is how to get it done.

A good practice is to put your extensions to core objects in a separate file (like `string_ex.rb`) or a sub-directory(like `extensions` or `core_ext`).  This way, it is obvious what has been extended, and it is easy for someone to see how they have been extended or changed.

Where monkey patching can go bad is when you change some existing behavior of a core object that causes some other code that expects the original functionality to misbehave.

Answer (score 2):

The `object` class defines `send`, and all objects inherit this. You "send" an object the `send` method. The `send` method's parameters are the method-you-want-to-invoke's name as a symbol, followed by any arguments and an optional block. You can also use `__send__`.

```
>> "heya".send :reverse
=> "ayeh"

>> space = %w( moon star sun galaxy )
>> space.send(:collect) { |el| el.send :upcase! }
=> ["MOON", "STAR", "SUN", "GALAXY"]
```

**Edit..**

You probably want to use the `define_method` method:

```
String.class_eval {
  define_method :hello do |name|
    self.gsub(/(\w+)/,'hello') + " #{name}"
  end
}

puts "Once upon a time".hello("Dylan")
# >> hello hello hello hello Dylan
```

That adds instance methods. To add class methods:

```
eigenclass = class << String; self; end
eigenclass.class_eval {
  define_method :hello do
    "hello"
  end
}

puts String.hello
# >> hello
```

You can't define methods that expect a block though.

It might be a good thing to have a read of [this chapter from Why's Poignant Guide](http://poignantguide.net/ruby/chapter-6.html), you can skip down to "Dwemthy’s Array" to get to the meta-programming stuff.

Comment: I was trying to temporarily avoid jumping into meta-programming just yet. But I guess it's just inevitable if I want to get past hello-world-ish stuff.
My idea about using a evals is bascially runtime-monkeypatching. But I now see how everything else is just that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys.

All of the suggested implementation work. More importantly, I learned to weigh in the case in hand and decide if re-opening core (or library) classes is a good idea or not.

FWIW, a friend pointed out the `send` implementation I was looking for. But now that I look at it, it's even closer to monkeypatching than all the other implementations :)

```
module M
    def do_magic
    ....
    end
end
String.send(:include, M)
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to attaching functions to classes or objects, you can always go the functional route:

```
class StringMagic
  def self.do(string)
     ...
  end
end

StringMagic.do("I'm a String.") # => "I'm a MAGIC String!"
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try [refinements](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html):

```rb
module StringPatch
  refine String do
    def downcase
      self.reverse # for demonstration purposes
    end
  end
end
```

Use it:

```rb
require_relative 'string_patch'

module Foo
  using StringPatch

  def self.bar
    'BAR'.downcase
  end
end

p Foo.bar # => RAB
p 'BAR'.downcase # => bar
```

Here, we've namespaced the (rather contrived) monkeypatch strictly to the `module Foo` scope. Normal functionality is restored outside of the module. This works on classes as well. We could also scope to the file:

```rb
require_relative 'string_patch'

p 'BAR'.downcase # => bar

using StringPatch

module Foo
  def self.bar
    'BAR'.downcase
  end
end

p Foo.bar # => RAB
p 'BAR'.downcase # => RAB
```

If the [benefits aren't clear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15224035/6243352), namespacing the monkeypatch gives the ability to use fluent monkeypatch syntax within a particular module, class or file but without the risk of clashes when using other libraries that monkeypatch `String`, like activesupport.

See [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The "monkey patch" you describe could indeed be a problem if someone else wants to require your code (as a gem, for example).  Who is to say they won't also want to add a String method that is called do_magic?  One method will overwrite the other, and this can be challenging to debug.  If there is any chance your code will be open source, then it is best to create your own class:

```
class MyString < String
  def initialize(str)
    @str = str
  end
  def do_magic
    ...magic done on @str
    @str
  end
end
```

Now, if you need to do_magic you can

```
magic_str = MyString.new(str).do_magic
```