# Applying Refinement feature in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to refine 'get' method inside HTTP class with no success. 
I anticipate to get 'HTTP#get in Faker" in output; but the program runs the original 'get' method inside Net::HTTP.
Are we allowed to do the following code in Ruby 2.1?

```
require 'net/http'
module Faker
  refine Net::HTTP do
    def self.get(dummy)
      puts "HTTP#get in Faker"
    end
  end
end

using Faker
uri = URI('http://www.google.com')
x = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
```

Comment: refinements are *not* supposed to be applied on class methods, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220526/are-refinements-in-ruby-2-0-totally-useless) question

Comment: ok, this explains my problem then. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. 
We can refine class methods using this trick:

Here, it is:

```
require 'net/http'
include Net
module Faker
  refine Class do
    def HTTP.get(dummy)
      puts "HTTP#get in M"
    end
  end
end

using Faker
uri = URI('http://www.google.com')
x = HTTP.get(uri)
```

Answer (score 1):

Class method can be refined via `singleton_class` of the class you would like to refine:

```
require 'net/http'

module Faker
  refine Net::HTTP.singleton_class do
    def get(dummy)
      puts "HTTP#get in Faker"
    end
  end
end

using Faker
uri = URI('http://www.google.com')
x = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
```