# How to use Ruby Module?

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching, ruby-1.9.3

The following code works fine:

```
class Float
  def round
   self.format.to_f
  end

  def format
    "%.2f" % self
  end
end
```

However, it seems bad practice to monkeypatch a class like Float because other people are doing the same thing and it causes problems.

Then I installed simplecov and the problem started: simplecov monkeypatches the same methods.

So I created a module and mixed it in to Float.

```
module MyModule
  def round
   self.format.to_f
  end

  def format
    "%.2f" % self
  end
end
```

Which I guess works as well. But the problem is that simplecov seems to be overwriting the mixed-in method above.

So, what is the proper way to extend built-in classes so that they do not conflict with other people's code?

Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: IMO, you should not be doing that in the `Float` class, no matter how good it feels to be able to do `100.76572324.round`. Especially, `format` is a presentation concern and should not be defined on `Float`. [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/a/238921/382818)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use just argument on the `round` call?

```
13.6657.round(2)    # => 13.67
```

But if you are sure you need module (to possibly adjust the format for all Floats out there, I'd propose you just define `format` method as such:

```
module MyModule
  def format
    ("%.2f" % self).to_f
  end
end
```

And mix this in to Float.
And later in code you call the `format` method instead of round:

```
13.6657.format     # => 13.67
```

This way it does not hurt the core functionality (as your initial code dropped the argument from the `round` definition).

Even better - if you want (can) pinpoint the monkey-patching, simply extend specific instance:

```
a = 13.6657
a.extend MyModule

a.format           # => 13.67
```

This way it wont mess with other Floats, but you can still adjust the format without finding all calls to `a.round(2)` in your code.

Comment: That's helpful. I did do the second suggestion, mix MyMyodule into float. But simplecov overwrites the mixed-in method.