# Convert to/from DateTime and Time in Ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime, time

How do you convert between a DateTime and a Time object in Ruby?

Comment: I'm not sure if this should be a seperate question, but how do you convert between a Date and a Time?

Comment: The accepted and highest-rated answers are no longer the most accurate under modern versions of Ruby. See the answers [by @theTinMan](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8511699/405017) and [by @PatrickMcKenzie](http://stackoverflow.com/a/280026/405017) below.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You'll need two slightly different conversions.

To convert from  `Time`  to  `DateTime` you can amend the Time class as follows:

```
require 'date'
class Time
  def to_datetime
    # Convert seconds + microseconds into a fractional number of seconds
    seconds = sec + Rational(usec, 10**6)

    # Convert a UTC offset measured in minutes to one measured in a
    # fraction of a day.
    offset = Rational(utc_offset, 60 * 60 * 24)
    DateTime.new(year, month, day, hour, min, seconds, offset)
  end
end
```

Similar adjustments to Date will let you convert  `DateTime`  to  `Time` .

```
class Date
  def to_gm_time
    to_time(new_offset, :gm)
  end

  def to_local_time
    to_time(new_offset(DateTime.now.offset-offset), :local)
  end

  private
  def to_time(dest, method)
    #Convert a fraction of a day to a number of microseconds
    usec = (dest.sec_fraction * 60 * 60 * 24 * (10**6)).to_i
    Time.send(method, dest.year, dest.month, dest.day, dest.hour, dest.min,
              dest.sec, usec)
  end
end
```

Note that you have to choose between local time and GM/UTC time.

Both the above code snippets are taken from O'Reilly's [Ruby Cookbook](http://safari.oreilly.com/0596523696). Their code reuse [policy](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/oreilly/ask_tim/2001/codepolicy.html) permits this.

Comment: This will break on 1.9 where DateTime#sec_fraction returns the number of milliseconds in one second. For 1.9 you want to use: usec = dest.sec_fraction * 10**6

Answer (score 194):

```
require 'time'
require 'date'

t = Time.now
d = DateTime.now

dd = DateTime.parse(t.to_s)
tt = Time.parse(d.to_s)
```

Comment: +1 This may not be the most efficient in execution, but it works, it's concise, and it's very readable.

Comment: Unfortunately this only really works when dealing with local times. If you start with a DateTime or Time with a different timezone, the parse function will convert into local timezone. You basically lose the original timezone.

Comment: As of ruby 1.9.1, DateTime.parse does preserve timezone. (I do not have access to earlier versions.)

Time.parse doesn't preserve timezone, because it represents the POSIX-standard time_t, which I believe is an integer difference from epoch.  Any conversion to Time should have the same behaviour.

Comment: You're right. DateTime.parse works in 1.9.1 but not Time.parse. In any case, it's less error prone (consistent) and likely faster to use DateTime.new(...) and Time.new(..). See my answer for sample code.

Comment: @Alkaline, I am not sure I get what you mean.  This method is consistent and error free.  Do you have any good reasons for implying otherwise?

Comment: Hi @anshul. I'm not implying I'm stating :-). Timezone info is not kept when using Time.parse(). It's easy to test. In your code above, simply replace    d = DateTime.now
with    d = DateTime.new(2010,01,01, 10,00,00, Rational(-2, 24)). 

tt will now show the date d converted into your local timezone. You can still do date arithmetics and all but the original tz info is lost. This info is a context for the date and it is often important.

See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279769/convert-to-from-datetime-and-time-in-ruby/3513247#3513247

Comment: @Alkaline: `Time` does not store time zone information and this is the intended behaviour. Thus, no method of converting a `DateTime` to `Time` will "preserve" timezone.

Comment: @asnhul. The Ruby 1.9 Time class does support timezone. I keep repeating the same thing but just check the answer I gave below. It has code that converts from DateTime to Time and back to DateTime while preserving the timezone info. The Ruby Time class is a wrapper for the C Standard Library time functions and those don't support timezone (it's stripped). That's true except that the timezone support is implemented in the ruby wrapper. Just check the time.rb file in the Ruby src distribution. Or, just run my sample code to convince yourself.

Comment: all time and dates on the server should be in UTC anyway haha

Comment: I think it is much more preferable to use `t.to_datetime` than convert to string and thatn parse to datetime.

Answer (score 68):

As an update to the state of the Ruby ecosystem, `Date`, `DateTime` and `Time` now have methods to convert between the various classes. Using Ruby 1.9.2+:

```
pry
[1] pry(main)> ts = 'Jan 1, 2000 12:01:01'
=> "Jan 1, 2000 12:01:01"
[2] pry(main)> require 'time'
=> true
[3] pry(main)> require 'date'
=> true
[4] pry(main)> ds = Date.parse(ts)
=> #<Date: 2000-01-01 (4903089/2,0,2299161)>
[5] pry(main)> ds.to_date
=> #<Date: 2000-01-01 (4903089/2,0,2299161)>
[6] pry(main)> ds.to_datetime
=> #<DateTime: 2000-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 (4903089/2,0,2299161)>
[7] pry(main)> ds.to_time
=> 2000-01-01 00:00:00 -0700
[8] pry(main)> ds.to_time.class
=> Time
[9] pry(main)> ds.to_datetime.class
=> DateTime
[10] pry(main)> ts = Time.parse(ts)
=> 2000-01-01 12:01:01 -0700
[11] pry(main)> ts.class
=> Time
[12] pry(main)> ts.to_date
=> #<Date: 2000-01-01 (4903089/2,0,2299161)>
[13] pry(main)> ts.to_date.class
=> Date
[14] pry(main)> ts.to_datetime
=> #<DateTime: 2000-01-01T12:01:01-07:00 (211813513261/86400,-7/24,2299161)>
[15] pry(main)> ts.to_datetime.class
=> DateTime
```

Comment: DateTime.to_time returns a DateTime...

`1.9.3p327 :007 > ts = '2000-01-01 12:01:01 -0700'
 => "2000-01-01 12:01:01 -0700" 
1.9.3p327 :009 > dt = ts.to_datetime
 => Sat, 01 Jan 2000 12:01:01 -0700 
1.9.3p327 :010 > dt.to_time
 => Sat, 01 Jan 2000 12:01:01 -0700 
1.9.3p327 :011 > dt.to_time.class
 => DateTime`

Comment: Oops. Just realized that this is a Ruby on Rails issue not a Ruby issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277454/weird-ruby-behavior-in-datetime-to-time-conversion . They even had a bug filed against this method in the 2.x line and marked it "won't fix". Horrible decision IMHO. The Rails behavior totally breaks the underlying Ruby interface.

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately, the `DateTime.to_time, Time.to_datetime` and `Time.parse` functions don't retain the timezone info. Everything is converted to local timezone during conversion. Date arithmetics still work but you won't be able to display the dates with their original timezones. That context information is often important. For example, if I want to see transactions performed during business hours in New York I probably prefer to see them displayed in their original timezones, not my local timezone in Australia (which 12 hrs ahead of New York).

The conversion methods below do keep that tz info.

For Ruby 1.8, look at [Gordon Wilson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279769/convert-to-from-datetime-and-time-in-ruby/279785#279785). It's from the good old reliable Ruby Cookbook.

For Ruby 1.9, it's slightly easier.

```
require 'date'

# Create a date in some foreign time zone (middle of the Atlantic)
d = DateTime.new(2010,01,01, 10,00,00, Rational(-2, 24))
puts d

# Convert DateTime to Time, keeping the original timezone
t = Time.new(d.year, d.month, d.day, d.hour, d.min, d.sec, d.zone)
puts t

# Convert Time to DateTime, keeping the original timezone
d = DateTime.new(t.year, t.month, t.day, t.hour, t.min, t.sec, Rational(t.gmt_offset / 3600, 24))
puts d
```

This prints the following

```
2010-01-01T10:00:00-02:00
2010-01-01 10:00:00 -0200
2010-01-01T10:00:00-02:00
```

The full original DateTime info including timezone is kept.

Comment: Time is complicated, but there's no excuse for not providing built-in conversion between different built-in time classes.  You can throw a RangeException if you try to get a UNIX time_t for 4713 BC (though a BigNum negative value would be nicer), but at least provide a method for it.

Comment: `Time#to_datetime` appears to preserve tz for me: `Time.local(0).to_datetime.zone #=> "-07:00"; Time.gm(0).to_datetime.zone #=> "+00:00"`

Comment: @Phrogz UTC offset is not the same thing as a time zone. One is constant, the other can change at different times of year for daylight saving time. DateTime doesn't have a zone, it ignores DST. Time respects it, but only in the "local" (system environment) TZ.

Comment: Now this is resolved, you can just do `.to_time`: `DateTime.new(2010,01,01, 10,00,00, Rational(-2, 24)).to_time == Time.new(d.year, d.month, d.day, d.hour, d.min, d.sec, d.zone)` (`2010-01-01T10:00:00-02:00 / 2010-01-01 10:00:00 -0200`)

Answer (score 1):

Improving on Gordon Wilson solution, here is my try:

```
def to_time
  #Convert a fraction of a day to a number of microseconds
  usec = (sec_fraction * 60 * 60 * 24 * (10**6)).to_i
  t = Time.gm(year, month, day, hour, min, sec, usec)
  t - offset.abs.div(SECONDS_IN_DAY)
end
```

You'll get the same time in UTC, loosing the timezone (unfortunately)

Also, if you have ruby 1.9, just try the `to_time` method

Answer (score 0):

While making such conversions one should take into consideration the behavior of timezones while converting from one object to the other. I found some good notes and examples in this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21075654).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `to_date`, e.g.

```rb
> Event.last.starts_at
=> Wed, 13 Jan 2021 16:49:36.292979000 CET +01:00
> Event.last.starts_at.to_date
=> Wed, 13 Jan 2021
```