# get next/previous month from a Time object

Tags: ruby

I have a Time object and would like to find the next/previous month. Adding subtracting days does not work as the days per month vary.

```
time = Time.parse('21-12-2008 10:51 UTC')
next_month = time + 31 * 24 * 60 * 60
```

Incrementing the month also falls down as one would have to take care of the rolling

```
time = Time.parse('21-12-2008 10:51 UTC')
next_month = Time.utc(time.year, time.month+1)

time = Time.parse('01-12-2008 10:51 UTC')
previous_month = Time.utc(time.year, time.month-1)
```

The only thing I found working was

```
time = Time.parse('21-12-2008 10:51 UTC')
d = Date.new(time.year, time.month, time.day)
d >>= 1
next_month = Time.utc(d.year, d.month, d.day, time.hour, time.min, time.sec, time.usec)
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this that I am not seeing?
How would you do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are no built-in methods on `Time` to do what you want in Ruby. I suggest you write methods to do this work in a module and extend the `Time` class to make their use simple in the rest of your code.

You can use `DateTime`, but the methods (`<<` and `>>`) are not named in a way that makes their purpose obvious to someone that hasn't used them before.

Answer (score 95):

#### Ruby on Rails

*Note: This **only works in Rails** (Thanks Steve!) but I'm keeping it here in case others are using Rails and wish to use these more intuitive methods.*

Super simple - thank you Ruby on Rails!

```
Time.now + 1.month

Time.now - 1.month
```

Or, another option if it's in relation to the **current time** (Rails 3+ only).

```
1.month.from_now

1.month.ago
```

Comment: The `#month` method is a Rails extension. It also assumes 30 days in a month, and so will return the wrong answer on the 31st.

Comment: Fairplay, I was using the script/console - guess I'm too ROR'd for my own good.

Comment: @Steve it doesn't assume 30 days when doing date arithmetic. It's actually pretty magical. try it! (see ActiveSupport::Duration, Date#plus_with_duration, and integer/time.rb in active_support). e.g. >> Time.utc(2010, 2, 1) + 1.months. 
=> Mon Mar 01 00:00:00 UTC 2010
>> Time.utc(2010, 3, 1) + 1.months
=> Thu Apr 01 00:00:00 UTC 2010
>> Time.utc(2010, 4, 1) + 1.months
=> Sat May 01 00:00:00 UTC 2010

Or for an extreme example: >> Time.utc(2010, 1, 31) + 1.months
=> Sun Feb 28 00:00:00 UTC 2010

Comment: >> Time.utc(2010, 1, 31) + 1.months
=> Sun Feb 28 00:00:00 UTC 2010
>> Time.utc(2008, 1, 31) + 1.months
=> Fri Feb 29 00:00:00 UTC 2008

Comment: @John: That's new, isn't it? Do you know what version of Rails added that?

Comment: @Steve 2007ish? http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/276c9f29cde80fafa23814b0039f67504255e0fd

Comment: 1.month.ago is easier (RoR)

Comment: @joaomilho For Rails 3+, for sure. I added it to the answer, thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't this be Time.now (Rather than DateTime.now) since 1.month returns a TIme object with timezone.

Comment: @Donato Your comment made me look up the main differences between `DateTime` and `Time`. Prior to Ruby 1.9, `DateTime` was a better choice but Ruby 1.9 and above, `Time` appears to be a better. Thanks for the nudge. Read more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21075654/293280

Answer (score 27):

Personally I prefer using:

```
Time.now.beginning_of_month - 1.day      # previous month
Time.now.end_of_month + 1.day            # next month
```

It always works and is independent from the number of days in a month.

Find more info [in this API doc](http://apidock.com/rails/Time/beginning_of_month)

Comment: Best answer so far

Comment: This is strange to me, but it works if you what you really want is the last day of the previous month or the first day of the next month. If all you want is the previous or next _month_ and could care less about what _day_ of that month, there's easier and more simplistic ways to get it.

Answer (score 14):

you can use standard class DateTime

```
require 'date'

dt = Time.new().to_datetime
=> #<DateTime: 2010-04-23T22:31:39+03:00 (424277622199937/172800000,1/8,2299161)>

dt2 = dt >> 1
=> #<DateTime: 2010-05-23T22:31:39+03:00 (424282806199937/172800000,1/8,2299161)>

t = dt2.to_time
=> 2010-05-23 22:31:39 +0200
```

Answer (score 8):

below it works

previous month:

```
Time.now.months_since(-1)
```

next month:

```
Time.now.months_since(1)
```

Comment: undefined method `months_since'

Comment: what's your code environment, ruby version ? here is my code execute results `irb(main):053:0> Time.now.months_since(-1)
=> 2013-10-19 08:40:04 +0800`

Comment: $ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-darwin12.2.1]
$ irb
>> Time.now.months_since(-1)
NoMethodError: undefined method `months_since' for 2013-11-19 02:09:23 +0100:Time

Comment: months_since is activesupports's methods, you can execute `ri months_since` in your cli

Answer (score 8):

If you do not want to load and rely on additional libraries you can use something like:

```
module MonthRotator
  def current_month
    self.month
  end

  def month_away
    new_month, new_year = current_month == 12 ? [1, year+1] : [(current_month + 1), year]
    Time.local(new_year, new_month, day, hour, sec)
  end

  def month_ago
    new_month, new_year = current_month == 1 ? [12, year-1] : [(current_month - 1), year]
    Time.local(new_year, new_month, day, hour, sec)
  end
end

class Time
  include MonthRotator
end


require 'minitest/autorun'

class MonthRotatorTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  describe "A month rotator Time extension" do
    it 'should return a next month' do
      next_month_date = Time.local(2010, 12).month_away
      assert_equal next_month_date.month, 1
      assert_equal next_month_date.year, 2011
    end

    it 'should return previous month' do
      previous_month_date = Time.local(2011, 1).month_ago
      assert_equal previous_month_date.month, 12
      assert_equal previous_month_date.year, 2010
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This does not take year rolling into account.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer that doesn't rely on active_support / rails.

Answer (score 6):

I just want to add my plain ruby solution for completeness
replace the format in strftime to desired output

```
DateTime.now.prev_month.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
DateTime.now.next_month.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try convert to datetime.

Time gives you current date, and DateTime allows you to operate with.

Look at this:

```
irb(main):041:0> Time.new.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        => "21/05/2015"

irb(main):040:0> Time.new.to_datetime.prev_month.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    => "21/04/2015"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution on plain ruby without RoR, works on old ruby versions.

```
t=Time.local(2000,"jan",1,20,15,1,0);
curmon=t.mon;
prevmon=(Time.local(t.year,t.mon,1,0,0,0,0)-1).mon ;
puts "#{curmon} #{prevmon}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the solutions assume rails. But, in pure ruby you can do the following

```
require 'date'    

d = Date.now
last_month = d<<1

last_month.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Im using the ActiveSupport::TimeZone for this example, but just in case you are using Rails or ActiveSupport it might come in handy.**

If you want the previous month you can substract 1 month

```
time = Time.zone.parse('21-12-2008 10:51 UTC')
time.ago(1.month)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the previous month info by this code

```
require 'time'
time = Time.parse('2021-09-29 12:31 UTC')
time.prev_month.strftime("%b %Y")
```

Comment: undefined method `prev_month' for 2021-09-29 12:31:00 UTC:Time (NoMethodError)

Answer (score -2):

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> time = Time.now
=> 2016-11-21 10:16:31 -0800
irb(main):002:0> year = time.year
=> 2016
irb(main):003:0> month = time.month
=> 11
irb(main):004:0> last_month = month - 1
=> 10
irb(main):005:0> puts time
2016-11-21 10:16:31 -0800
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> puts year
2016
=> nil
irb(main):007:0> puts month
11
=> nil
irb(main):008:0> puts last_month
10
=> nil
```

Comment: Don't try this in January though.