# Convert ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone to DateTime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I'm trying to step every N days between two dates. I tried the following code but is wasn't working because startDate and endDate are ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone objects and not DateTime objects like I thought.

```
startDate.step(endDate, step=7) { |d| puts d.to_s}
  min.step(max, step=stepInt){ |d|
  puts d.to_s  
}
```

How do I covert the TimeWithZone object to a DateTime?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`DateTime` is an old class which you generally want to avoid using. `Time` and `Date` are the two you want to be using. `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` acts like `Time`.

For stepping over dates you probably want to deal with `Date` objects. You can convert a `Time` (or `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`) into a `Date` with `Time#to_date`:

```
from.to_date.step(to.to_date, 7) { |d| puts d.to_s }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261329/whats-the-difference-between-datetime-and-time-in-ruby recommends DateTime as the best way to handle your Dates!

Comment: DateTime is a Ruby class. ActiveSupport::TimeWithZones is Rails. So saying that it's "old" and you should avoid it, isn't accurate. See ChrisJ's answer for a better response.

Comment: Postgres' 'Timestamp' converts to Rails' TimeWithZone, with is not at all friendly to display, so using DateTime is very often better, and here 4 years later it is still not old.

Comment: Why do I want to avoid using DateTime? DateTime is an aggregate of Date and Time. So if I need date plus time, I should use DateTime, no? Although it does appear that Time gives you date too. Plus with Time, you can use zone e.g. Time.zone.now  => Tue, 02 Jun 2015 14:01:58 EDT -04:00, which gives you date and time and timezone.

Comment: @Donato You want to avoid using DateTime because Time.zone can do everything DateTime can do, and is easier to always remember to use than remembering adding a `.in_time_zone` after your datetimes specifically. More examples and reasoning here: http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/

Comment: @IanM TimeWithZone can be displayed exactly the same as DateTime, if you want. By default it displays no different than merely having ie. `CEST +02:00` instead of `+0200` at the end..

Answer (score 40):

I thought it might be useful to update this answer as I was searching this up recently. The easiest way to achieve this conversion is using the .to_datetime() function.

e.g.

```
5.hours.from_now.class              # => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
5.hours.from_now.to_datetime.class  # => DateTime
```

ref: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-to_datetime