# Which should I always parse date times with? DateTime, Time, Time.zone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails, I see I have a few options to parse a date and a date-time.  What is the best practice for parsing dates for the sole purpose of persisting them into the DB via ActiveRecord?  And why?

```
Time.zone.parse(...)
Time.parse(...)
DateTime.parse(...)
```

Comment: Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138515/when-should-i-use-datetime-vs-date-time-fields-in-ruby-rails) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261329/whats-the-difference-between-datetime-and-time-in-ruby/1261435#1261435), which says to use DateTime when dealing with Dates or Dates far out in the future.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go with Time.zone.parse if you just want to write into ActiveRecord.

DateTime should be avoided.  If you're handling dates, you should use Date.parse instead.

Beyond that, it depends on whether the input comes with timezone information, what the current timezone is set to, and whether you want timezones in your data.

Time.zone.parse will return an ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone, defaulting to UTC.

```
> Time.zone.parse("12:30")
=> Thu, 10 May 2012 12:30:00 UTC +00:00
```

Time.parse will return a Time, with a zone if it's specified in the input, or the local TZ.

```
> Time.parse("12:30")
=> 2012-05-09 12:30:00 -0700
```

For a more detailed explanation of Ruby time comparisons and precision, read this blog post:

http://blog.solanolabs.com/rails-time-comparisons-devil-details-etc/

Comment: Time.zone.parse "defaults" to UTC if your Rails app is defaulted to UTC (in environment.rb)... Time.parse defaults to the server local time zone offset regardless of the Rails app.

Comment: Hey, `Time.zone.parse` takes the rails default zone correctly, while DateTime returns UTC. so +1, but is there any other reason for "DateTime should be avoided."?

Answer (score 2):

Times that are automatically set by ActiveRecord (e.g. `created_at` and `updated_at`) come back as [`ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) instances.

According to the documentation, `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` and `Time` have the same API, so `Time` is what I would use.

On an unrelated note, there are methods `to_time` and `to_datetime` that you can call on strings:

```
"2012-05-09".to_time # => 2012-05-09 00:00:00 UTC 
"2012-05-09".to_datetime # => Wed, 09 May 2012 00:00:00 +0000
```