# Why is this iso8601 date parsing with an offset of +2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, activesupport, iso8601, datetimeoffset

I have the following JSON:

```
{"dtime" : "2020-08-26T15:30:00+03:00"}
```

Parsing it, yields the following date:

```
=> 2020-08-26 14:30:00 +0200
```

Why does it have a +2 offset and not a +3 one?

EDIT: I'm using Rails 3.2.13, with ActiveSupport 3.2.13. I'm trying to parse the string by using:

```
Time.parse(string)
```

I've noticed, however, that if I parse it with:

```
DateTime.parse(string)
```

I get a correct offset.

Comment: What's your timezone?

Comment: Europe/Bucharest, +03:00

Comment: And the server or browser or whatever you're using to do the parsing?  It looks like it has its output format set to a different timezone.

Comment: Please show whatever code you are parsing it with, and indicate what language or platform.  Thanks.

Comment: Matt, I've updated the question.

Comment: Then just use `DateTime`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13199003/634824

Comment: I am. I don't understand the different behaviour of the parsing methods, but, I guess I will stick with what it works. I've also opened an issue on github https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12027

Answer (score 1):

I have no business answering this question, because I don't use Ruby. That said, just looking at the standard library, it seems the reason is [`Time.parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-i-parse) includes a [call](https://github.com/rubysl/rubysl-time/blob/8677a31f18afaaab45476c0513a19d9b88fea5ef/lib/rubysl/time/time.rb#L261) to [`localtime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Time.html#method-i-localtime), which converts the parse result into your local time zone.

I suspect you're actually executing this code in GMT +02. You can check with `Time.new`. I'm running in GMT -07.

```
>> Time.new
=> 2014-05-16 18:51:00 -0700
```

You can convert the result into any time zone by passing it to `localtime`.

```
>> require 'Time'
=> true
>> t = Time.parse("2020-08-26T15:30:00+03:00")
=> 2020-08-26 05:30:00 -0700
>> t.localtime("+03:00")
=> 2020-08-26 15:30:00 +0300
```