# Ruby on Rails parsing time from datetime, not as string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I'm trying to extract the time component from a DateTime object (which is represented as "at" in my example). How do I do this, I am absolutely stumped? (I don't want to parse it to a string with `strftime` as i did here):

```
@session_date.at.strftime("%H:%M")
```

I would really like to return the hours and minutes as a Time object.

Comment: Why not? This seems to be the canonical way to do so?

Comment: Because for my purposes I don't want the DateTime object parsed to a string, I need the minutes and hours to test later if it falls between a start and end time (both Time objects)

Comment: Read @Jordan's response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you want a Time object?

Just so we're clear, the [Time](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Time.html) class in Ruby isn't just "DateTime without the date." As "[What's the difference between DateTime and Time in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261329/whats-the-difference-between-datetime-and-time-in-ruby/1261435#1261435)" explains, "Time is a wrapper around POSIX-standard time_t, or seconds since January 1, 1970." Like DateTime, a Time object still has year, month, and day, so you don't really gain anything by using Time instead. There's not really a way to represent just hour and minute using either Time or DateTime.

The best you could do with Time, I think, would be this:

```
date_time = DateTime.now
seconds = date_time.hour * 60 * 60 + date_time.minute * 60

time = Time.at(seconds)
# => 1970-01-01 09:58
```

...but then you still have to call `time.hour` and `time.min` to get at the hour and minute.

If you're just looking for a lightweight data structure to represent an hour and minute pair, though, you might as well just roll your own:

```
HourAndMinute = Struct.new(:hour, :minute) do
  def self.from_datetime(date_time)
    new(date_time.hour, date_time.minute)
  end
end

hm = HourAndMinute.from_datetime(DateTime.now)
# => #<struct HourAndMinute hour=15, minute=58>
hm.to_h
# => { :hour => 15, :minute => 58 }
hm.to_a
# => [ 15, 58 ]
```

---

#### Edit re:

> I have a variable that stores an appointment -- this variable is a DateTime object. I have two table fields that store the start and end times of a location. I need to check if the time scheduled for that appointment lies between the start and end times.

Ah, it seems you had a bit of a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). This makes a lot more sense now.

Absent any more information, I'm going to assume your "fields that store the start and end times of a location" are MySQL `TIME` columns called `start_time` and `end_time`. Given MySQL TIME columns, Rails casts the values to Time objects [with the date component set to 1/1/2000](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb#L286-L293). So if your database has the values `start_time = '09:00'` and `end_time = '17:00'`, Rails will give you Time objects like this:

```
start_time = Time.new(2000, 1, 1, 9, 0) # => 2000-01-01 09:00:00 ...
end_time = Time.new(2000, 1, 1, 17, 0)  # => 2000-01-01 17:00:00 ...
```

Now you say your appointment time is a DateTime, so let's call it `appointment_datetime` and suppose it's at 10:30am tomorrow:

```
appointment_datetime = DateTime.new(2014, 11, 18, 10, 30) # => 2014-11-18 10:30:00 ...
```

So now to rephrase your question: How do we tell if the *time* part of `appointment_datetime` is between the *time* part of `start_time` and `end_time`. The answer is, we need to either change the *date* part of `start_time` and `end_time` to match the *date* part of `appointment_datetime`, or the other way around. Since it's easier to change one thing than two, let's do it the other way around and change `appointment_datetime` to match `start_time` and `end_time` (and, since those two are Time objects, we'll create a Time object):

```
appointment_time = DateTime.new(2000, 1, 1, appointment_datetime.hour, appointment_datetime.minute)
# => 2000-01-01 10:30:00 ...
```

Now we can compare them directly:

```
if appointment_time >= start_time && appointment_time <= end_time
  puts "Appointment time is good!"
end

# Or, more succinctly:
if (start_time..end_time).cover?(appointment_time)
  puts "Appointment time is good!"
end
```

You would, of course, want to wrap all of this up in a method, perhaps in your Location model (which, again, I'm assuming has `start_time` and `end_time` attributes):

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def appointment_time_good?(appointment_datetime)
    appointment_time = DateTime.new(2000, 1, 1,
                         appointment_datetime.hour, appointment_datetime.minute)

    (start_time..end_time).cover?(appointment_time)
  end
end

location = Location.find(12) # => #<Location id: 12, ...>
location.appointment_time_good?(appointment_time) # => true
```

I hope that's helpful!

P.S. Another way to implement this would be to ditch the date/time objects entirely and do a straight numeric comparison:

```
def appointment_time_good?(appointment_datetime)
  appointment_hour_min = [ appointment_datetime.hour, appointment_datetime.minute ]

  appointment_hour_min >= [ start_time.hour, start_time.min ]
    && appointment_hour_min <= [ end_time.hour, end_time.min ]
end
```

Comment: Hmm I don't think I want a key value pair.  Maybe if I elaborate on my purpose it might help.  I have a variable that stores an appointment -- this variable is a DateTime object.  I have two table fields that store the start and end times of a location.  I need to check if the time scheduled for that appointment lies between the start and end times.

Comment: Thank you very much!  That last part definitely solved my problem,  I would upvote you but sadly I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a DateTime object:

```
date_time = DateTime.now

date_time.hour
# => 16
date_time.minute
# => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the Time since now in words (which is common in Rails apps), then this may be a good read: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words