# undefined method `getlocal' for Sat, 30 Oct 2010 08:32:42 +0000:DateTime with Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting this error since I updated to `ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036)` & `Rails 3.0.1`. How can I fix it?

```
undefined method `getlocal' for Sat, 30 Oct 2010 08:32:42 +0000:DateTime

activesupport (3.0.1) lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb:75:in `localtime'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb:65:in `quoted_date'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:125:in `quoted_date'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb:31:in `quote'
```

Thanks for reading.

EDIT:

application.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'Brisbane'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Brisbane'
```

Comment: have you set your timezone in environment.rb ?

Comment: @Rishav Rastogi - I've got it in application.rb (pasted in above). Should that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeh that won't work,

The getlocal method is defined, for the Time class, and not for the DateTime class ( the object in your case is a DateTime object ).

DateTime#to_time is not a full proof solution to convert a DateTime Object to Time object.

Take a look at the link below for details on how to convert a DateTime object to a Time object

[Convert to/from DateTime and Time in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279769/convert-to-from-datetime-and-time-in-ruby)

Hope that helps