# 'T' getting added into my datetimes Ruby & Resque

Tags: ruby, redis, resque

For some reason when I pass my datetimes onto another class with Resque.enqueue I am getting a 'T' added where there was whitespace after the date and other whitespace is being removed...

This is the method:

```
def self.enqueue_job(start_date, end_date, type, date_type)
    query = [start_date, end_date, type, date_type].join(',')
    begin
        Resque.enqueue(Reports::Generator, start_date, end_date, type, date_type)
        add_to_queue(query)
    rescue Resque::TermException
        Resque.enqueue(Reports::Generator, start_date, end_date, type, date_type)
    end
  end
```

Which sets the query variable to:

"2013-05-31 07:59:59 -0700,2013-06-05 07:59:59 -0700,None,created_at"

But when I run

```
@query = [start_date, end_date, type, date_type].join(',')
```

from the Generator model above, @query equates to:

"2013-05-31T07:59:59-07:00,2013-06-05T07:59:59-07:00,None,created_at"

I am guessing it has something to do with Resque.enqueue, but do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. The issue was with the conversion for Time and DateTime. I was setting the value to Time before passing into the Generator class and somewhere along the lines it was being converted into DateTime.

Here is the post that helped me come to this conclusion: 
[Weird Ruby Behavior in DateTime to Time conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277454/weird-ruby-behavior-in-datetime-to-time-conversion)