# Comparing times only, without dates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to write a method that will check if `Time.now` is in between the open hours and the close hours of a shop.

The open and close hours are saved as a Time object but I can't compare it corectly because the shop saved its hours at `2012/2/2` so the open hours will be something like:

```
2012-02-02 02:30:00 UTC
```

and `Time.now` will be:

```
07:23 +0200
```

How can I compare just the time part without the date part?

Comment: How about you try to extract the time from the date first? http://stackoverflow.com/a/280464/1004274

Comment: has any answer been helpful?

Comment: I don't believe that any of the answers to date (June 18, 2018) are correct because they don't consider the case where the shop is open at midnight. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50733988/find-out-if-current-time-is-between-two-times/50735709#50735709) SO question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the time is 0 in that case, what is else?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ, my memory is not great at the best of times, but I have no recollection of this two-year-old question. To answer your question I would have to familiarize myself with the question and all the answers, which would take too much time. All I can say is that my comment probably had to do with closing times preceding opening times on a 24-hour clock. For example, opening at 20:00 and closing at 04:00 (the next day).

Comment: @CarySwoveland this should be taken into account with additional condition check ) when end < begin

Answer (score 43):

You can compare the `Time` without a date part, for example, as follows:

```
time1.utc.strftime( "%H%M%S%N" ) <= time2.utc.strftime( "%H%M%S%N" )
```

Comment: if open time is 08 AM and close time is  01 AM. does it work ?

Comment: @Vishal but how do you wish for the code to work to?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I use postgres as db. i have two fields open_at, close_at , Datatype is time. In my case, store's open time is 8 AM and close time is 1:00 AM, it means store will close tomorrow's  1 AM. so my query fail because ,`open_at <= close_at` becomes false. can you help me to overcome this issue ?

Comment: @Vishal if type of the fields in ruby are strings, you can't compare them is such way, class of the variables in ruby must be only Time or DateTime to the that kind of comparison

Comment: Yes it is Time Class.  and it is storing in this format "2000-01-01 08:00:00"

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ when opening time is 8 AM and closing time is 1 AM. it is storing in this format ,open at "2000-01-01 08:00:00" ,  close_at "2000-01-01 01:00:00"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167413/discussion-between-vishal-and--).

Answer (score 5):

There is a nice library https://github.com/bokmann/business_time which will do this and more for you.

```
BusinessTime::Config.with(beginning_of_workday: "8:30 am", end_of_workday: "5:30 pm") do
  Time.now.during_business_hours?
end
```

It will do much more for you, like rolling a time to next or previous opening time, counting business hours between two timestamps, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can strip the Time into its hours, minutes and seconds.

As described in [Time Class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html):

```
t = Time.now
hour = t.hour
minute = t.min
seconds = t.sec
```

Since you need to just compare whether it's within 2 hours you can check it as below.

```
if hour > openingHour and hour < closingHour
```

Comment: How can the OP compare the three values?

Comment: Yes, and more: imagine a shop in San Francisco that closes at 5 p.m. Pacific, which is 00:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 4):

You can compare only time in rails without date part like:---
Here `post_review` is table and we are getting only these record of `post_review` which are `created_at` between 10 am ---5pm in any date

```
post_review.where("(created_at::time >= :start_time) AND (created_at::time <= :end_time)", 
    start_time: Time.parse("10 am").strftime("%r"),
    end_time:   Time.parse("5 pm").strftime("%r")
 )
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to compare the point of time directly, you can compare their offsets from a common reference (e.g. midnight). You might need to make sure all times are using the same time zone, depending on your use case.

In Rails, this can be done easily with one of the helpers such as `#seconds_since_midnight`:

```
#given
opening_hour = DateTime.new(2012,2,2,2,30,0)

#compare
now = DateTime.now.in_time_zone('UTC')
opening_hour_since_midnight = opening_hour.seconds_since_midnight
now_since_midnight = now.seconds_since_midnight
p 'shop opened' if now_since_midnight > opening_hour_since_midnight
```

Answer (score 2):

Try converting the Time into a number and strip off the days. Since the Time is represented as a number of seconds since the UNIX Epoch with the decimal being a fraction of the second, you can convert this number to a number of days with the fraction being a fraction of a day.

Day based number = Ruby Time Number / 60 / 60 / 24

You can then use the modulus operator to strip the day portion so all you have left to compare is the time. So you want something like this:

```
def is_open?(time)
  open_h=Time.parse('2012-02-02 02:30:00 UTC')
  close_h=Time.parse('2012-02-02 10:00:00 UTC')
  (((time.to_r / 60 / 60 / 24) % 1) >= ((open_h.to_r / 60 / 60 / 24) % 1)) && (((time.to_r / 60 / 60 / 24) % 1) <= ((close_h.to_r / 60 / 60 / 24) % 1))
end

is_open? (Time.parse('2013-01-01 09:58:00 UTC'))
=> true
is_open? (Time.parse('2013-01-01 12:58:00 UTC'))
=> false
```

Answer (score -1):

```
close_or_open_time_object.to_a.first(3).reverse <=> Time.now.to_a.first(3).reverse
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Try a time across the day boundary to see.

Answer (score -6):

This will work only for time being in 24 hour format and when start hour is less than end hour.

```
Time start = DateUtil.convertStringToTime(Object.getStartTime());
Time mid = DateUtil.convertStringToTime(time);
Time end = DateUtil.convertStringToTime(Object.getEndTime());

    if(mid.getHours()>start.getHours() && mid.getHours()< end.getHours())
    {
        flag=true;
    }
    else if(mid.getHours() == start.getHours() && mid.getHours() < end.getHours())
    {
        if(mid.getMinutes() > start.getMinutes())
        {               
            flag=true;              
        }
        else if(mid.getMinutes() == start.getMinutes())
        {               
            if(mid.getSeconds() >= start.getSeconds())
            {
                flag=true;
            }
        }
    }
    else if(mid.getHours() > start.getHours() && mid.getHours() == end.getHours())
    {
        if(mid.getMinutes() < end.getMinutes())
        {
            flag=true;
        }
        else if(mid.getMinutes() == end.getMinutes())
        {
            if(mid.getSeconds() <= end.getSeconds())
            {
                flag=true;
            }
        }
    }
    else if(mid.getHours() == start.getHours() && mid.getHours() == end.getHours())
    {
        if(mid.getMinutes() > start.getMinutes() && mid.getMinutes() < end.getMinutes())
        {
            flag=true;
        }           
        else if(mid.getMinutes() == start.getMinutes() && mid.getMinutes() < end.getMinutes())
        {
            if(mid.getSeconds() > start.getSeconds())
            {
                flag=true;
            }
        }
        else if(mid.getMinutes() > start.getMinutes() && mid.getMinutes() == end.getMinutes())
        {
            if(mid.getSeconds() < end.getSeconds())
            {
                flag=true;
            }
        }
        else if(mid.getMinutes() == start.getMinutes() && mid.getMinutes() == end.getMinutes())
        {
            if(mid.getSeconds() > start.getSeconds() && mid.getSeconds() < end.getSeconds())
            {
                flag=true;
            }
        }
    }
```