# Find out if current time is between two times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, date, time

I have two time columns stored in a Postgresql database: `open_time` and `close_time`. I'm trying to find out if the current time, ignoring the date, is between the two times, ignoring the dates.

This code compares the dates as well as the time:

```
current_time = Time.now
if current_time.between?(store.open_time, store.close_time)
  puts "IN BETWEEN"      
end
```

It doesn't work, for example, when `current_time # => 2018-06-06 23:59:49 -0600` and `open_time # => 2000-01-01 22:59:00 UTC`.

How do I get it to not include the dates, and just compare the times?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Time is a more precise notion than date. You cannot have a particular time without the notion of which date it is.

Comment: @sawa eh? Postgres [perfectly allows](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) storing times without a date and the fact that ruby does not provide a handy wrapper for it does not mean “time is more precise.” `DateTime` is.

Comment: [Comparing times only, without dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14329198/477037) is a similar question, although not Postgres specific.

Comment: @Stefan, a comment at the link you gave suggests that the earlier question is in fact Postgres-related, but it would be a shame to regard this question a dup because I do not believe any of the earlier answers are correct.

Comment: I really appreciate all the answers! I ended up taking ideas from all the answers, so I'm not really sure which of them to mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
current_time = Time.now
open_time = store.open_time
close_time = store.close_time
current_time -= current_time.beginning_of_day
open_time -= open_time.beginning_of_day
close_time -= close_time.beginning_of_day
if current_time.between?(open_time, close_time)
  puts "IN BETWEEN"      
end
```

or

```
current_time = Time.now
open_time = store.open_time
close_time = store.close_time
current_time = [current_time.hour, current_time.min, current_time.sec]
open_time = [open_time.hour, open_time.min, open_time.sec]
close_time = [close_time.hour, close_time.min, close_time.sec]
if open_time <=> current_time == -1 and current_time <=> close_time == -1
  puts "IN BETWEEN"      
end
```

Comment: `Array` does not declare `between?` you need to use smth like `open_time..close_time === current_time`.

Comment: @mudasobwa You are right. I was starting to feel something wrong about my answer. Thanks.

Comment: `Array` implements `<=>` but does *not* include `Comparable`!?

Comment: @Stefan Yes. It looks like `<=>` is defined, but `<` is not.

Comment: Apparently tokland requested this feature, but [Matz rejected it](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5574). What a pity.

Comment: Consider: what if the store is a bar?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Not sure what you mean. Can you expand on that?

Comment: The calculation is different if the "store" opens before, but closes after midnight, e.g `18:00` until `03:00`

Comment: I see. But the OP has not asked that kind of question. If that is indeed what the OP wants, then the OP is asking the wrong question.

Comment: The OP hasn't mentioned anything about opening hours. They only have a table column named `open_time`.

Comment: @sawa has hours some how been removed from the concept of time now? If so then what is `open_time` to you?

Answer (score 5):

```
require 'time'

TIME_FMT = "%H%M%S"

def store_open_now?(open_time, close_time)
  nt = Time.now.strftime(TIME_FMT)
  ot = open_time.strftime(TIME_FMT)
  ct = close_time.strftime(TIME_FMT)
  ot <= ct ? (nt >= ot && nt <= ct) : (nt >= ot || nt <= ct)
end
```

As I write, the time is now about 32 minutes past midnight.

```
Time.now.strftime(TIME_FMT)
  #=> "003252"
```

Suppose

```
open_time  = DateTime.parse("09:00")
  #=> #<DateTime: 2018-06-07T09:00:00+00:00 ((2458277j,32400s,0n),
  #               +0s,2299161j)>
close_time = DateTime.parse("17:00")
  #=> #<DateTime: 2018-06-07T17:00:00+00:00 ((2458277j,61200s,0n),
  #               +0s,2299161j)>
```

Then

```
open_time.strftime(TIME_FMT)
  #=> "090000"
close_time.strftime(TIME_FMT)
  #=> "170000"
store_open_now?(open_time, close_time)
  #=> false
```

Now suppose the open time is the same, but the close time is later.

```
close_time = DateTime.parse("01:00")
  #=> #<DateTime: 2018-06-07T01:00:00+00:00 ((2458277j,3600s,0n),
  #               +0s,2299161j)>
```

Then

```
close_time.strftime(TIME_FMT)
  #=> "010000"
store_open_now?(open_time, close_time)
  #=> true
```

Answer (score 2):

You could `CAST()` your `datetime` to `time` by using,

```
cast(tbl_store.open_time as time) as SomeVariable

cast(tbl_store.close_time as time) as SomeOtherVariable
```

That would give you the `time` only instead of the full `datetime` value that you had to begin with, which is what you wanted.

You can then use the same logic with your `curtime() between` to the get value that you were looking for.

Example:

```
SELECT
  CAST(tbl_store.open_time as TIME) as open_time,
  CAST(tbl_store.close_time as TIME) as close_time,
  CURTIME() BETWEEN (cast(tbl_store.open_time as TIME)) AND (cast(tbl_store.close_time as TIME)) as time_between
FROM
  tbl_store
```

[Working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6e052/1)

You can change the schema build in the fiddle to test the `datetime` values you desire.

Note that if you ever have a logic that will include midnight time, you will have to make a `CASE WHEN` logic against that, else it will fail and return 0, whereas it should return 1.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice. Let the database do database stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of ranges and how numeric strings are compared

```
r = Range.new('09:00', '18:00')

r.include?('08:59') # => false
r.include?('09:01') # => true
r.include?('18:01') # => false
```

Then we could use

```
open_hours_range = Range.new(open_time.strftime('%R'), close_time.strftime('%R'))
shop_open? = open_hours_range.include?(Time.now.strftime('%R'))
```