# Combining arrays of different objects in RoR and sorting by a date value on a different attribute on each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two arrays of objects in ruby on rails. I want to combine them and sort them by two different attributes. Is this possible?

One is an array of 'Post' records, and one is an array of 'Talk' records. They both need to be sorted by date. But for Post, the relevant attribute is created_at while for Talk it's date_given. This is the kind of headache that's making me consider eliminating the two different models and replacing them with a more flexible Post model.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I just tried something that worked, but am not sure if it's the best way to handle this issue. I just add a method to each model called sortable date, and set it to what I want. One gotcha with this was that created_at was a Time and date_given was DateTime, so I used this post to deal with that [Convert to/from DateTime and Time in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279769/convert-to-from-datetime-and-time-in-ruby)

```
talk.rb

def sortable_date
  date_given
end  

post.rb

def sortable_date
  created_at.to_datetime
end
```

Then in my controller -

```
@posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(3)
@talks = Talk.order('date_given DESC').limit(3)

@news = @posts + @talks
@news.sort_by! &:sortable_date
@news = @news[1..4]
```

And I just render @news in my view and it summons the appropriate partials nicely. I'd love some feedback.

Comment: This works great, this is just what I was looking for, thanks for sharing how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

```
posts = Post.all
talks = Talk.all
posts+talks.sort do |a,b|
   attr_a = a.kind_of?(Post) ? 'created_at' : 'date_given'
   attr_b = b.kind_of?(Post) ? 'created_at' : 'date_given'
   a.send(attr_a) <=> b.send(attr_b)
end
```

There should be a SQL way to do this, but well, this way is simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Have you gotten something like this to work before? I just tried it and got an ArgumentError - 'comparison of Talk with Post failed'

Comment: Hi, not ever need it, but this should have worked since it is not comparing Post with Talk, but the send(attr_a) result with send(attr_b) result. Can you add some debug info? (like line of error and contents of the variables on that line)

Comment: just did a test here and seems to work with 'updated_at' and 'creation_time' from my work db

Comment: Hmmm I just tried it a different way and ran into an error that was more informative - I was trying to compare Time (post.created_at) and DateTime (talk.date_given). I wonder if that was the issue here as well.

Comment: You can use `.to_time` in the datetime field and it should work. I'm positive the way I answered works as well.