# Parsing string "10:00AM" to DateTime Type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I'm reading strings off of html but want to store them in a database as a DateTime field type.  What is a simple way to do this while correctly preserving AM/PM data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your access layer for the database should support the Ruby [DateTime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) type, hence you can parse it as follows:

```
require 'date'

DateTime.parse("10:00AM") 
# => #<DateTime: 2013-08-11T10:00:00+00:00 ((2456516j,36000s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

The whole meridiem notation (AM/PM) is at the presentation level. Your database will store it in its DateTime structure and everytime your retrieve it back into Rails, you can get your presentation by using `strftime`

```
your_date.strftime("%I:%M%p") 
=> "10:00AM"
```

Comment: Thanks platzhirsch!
I tested this out on the console and it assumes today's date.  Is there a way to have it only save the time data independent of any date?

Comment: I am recording these times as the beginning/end of weekly events, and later down the road want to be able to compare using the time value to see which one starts earlier/later.  If I have a date associated with the time my comparisons will not be accurate.

Comment: @ChristophePrakash In this case you could convert between `Time` and `DateTime` format, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279769/convert-to-from-datetime-and-time-in-ruby