# Ruby Year-Month-Date of last Sunday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I need to calculate in the format of `2014-01-20` the last two Sundays.

So, `last_sunday = 2014-01-20` and `most_recent_sunday = 2014-01-26`.

I am using Rails 4.0 and Ruby 2.0. How can I get these dates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In rails 4:

```
most_recent_sunday = Time.now.sunday.to_s

last_sunday =        Time.now.last_week.sunday.to_s
```

To get it to the format you are after:

```
DateTime.parse(most_recent_sunday).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/DateAndTime/Calculations/sunday
http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/DateAndTime/Calculations/last_week

Comment: Thanks for the tips - There's some helpful information on this here in TinMan's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279769/convert-to-from-datetime-and-time-in-ruby

I actually had to attach a `.to_s` method on `most_recent_sunday` to get it to parse correctly, and include the dashes in the `.strftime` method. Also, `Time.now.sunday` actually returns this upcoming sunday, not the last sunday. Thanks for the help though, got me close enough to figure it out.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this won't generalize to e.g. "Time.now.tuesday"

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the [chronic gem](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic)

```
require 'chronic'
Chronic.parse("last sunday")
=> 2014-01-26 12:00:00 +0200
```

You can also use rail's active_support to subtract `7.days` from the date computed above =)

Answer (score 0):

```
[11] pry(main)> last_sunday = Time.now - (Time.now.wday + 7) * 86400
=> 2014-01-19 17:17:19 -0600
[12] pry(main)> most_recent_sunday = Time.now - (Time.now.wday) * 86400
=> 2014-01-26 17:18:03 -0600
```

Comment: FYI if you start with Date.today or Time.zone.today then you don't need the `* 86400` because you'll already be dealing with days. So it suffices to do something like `t = Date.today; t - t.wday % 7`.

Answer (score 0):

A pure Ruby solution:

```
require 'date'

last_two_weeks   = (Date.today-13)..Date.today
last_two_sundays = last_two_weeks.select &:sunday?

puts last_two_sundays #=> 2014-01-19, 2014-01-26
```