# Convert datetime to time object in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have a time like

> "estimatedTime": "2022-11-09T22:59:00Z"

as json, which is parsed into datetime and saved in the db (t.datetime "estimated_time").

I want to find the difference between this estimated time and the current time in hours.

Currently i am getting the current time using

> Time.now.utc

which is giving me the current time as Time object.

Please suggest on how to solve this issue and find the difference between them. First i cant quite figure how the conversion from json to datetime will look like. Additionally i am also confused as to how this datetime will then to converted to time object to find the difference. I am new to rails and ruby so i am getting confused.

ruby 2.7.5p203
Rails 4.2.11

I have tried various functions but it has led to more confusion as to what should be done here.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/280464/5783088?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any conversion here. Just use [the `-` (minus) method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html#method-i-2D) on Time/DateTime which gives the difference between two times in seconds as a float:

```
irb(main):013:0> Time.current - 1.hour.ago
=> 3599.9999717 # The rounding error is inherent to floats
```

This works even if *other* is a DateTime or ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone.

You can then use [`ActiveSupport::Duration`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html) to convert seconds to hours or any other unit of time:

```
irb(main):012:0> (Time.current - 1.day.ago).round.seconds.in_hours
=> 24.0
```

Rails also has a built in [`time_ago_in_words`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words) method to humanize times for your views.