# Substraction of timeformat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, timestamp, actionmailer

I' m building a rails application where I use action mailer. 
I wanna be able to send email per say 2 hours before a certain event.

```
def notification(user, event)
  @user = user
  @event = event
  @delivery_time = @event.start_at - INTERVAL '2 hour' 

  mail( to: @user.email,
  subject: "Upcoming event")
end
```

event.start_at is timestamp format.

would it be possible to do

```
 event.start_at - INTERVAL - '2 hours'
```

I know you can do something like that into postgresql

```
 timestamp '2001-09-28 23:00' - interval '23 hours'
```

according to 
[Postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-datetime.html) .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238684/subtract-n-hours-from-a-datetime-in-ruby

Comment: Rails support datetime methods like `2.hours`, `4.days`, `5.minutes` etc... so you can use `@event.start_at - 2.hours`

Answer (score 0):

Like sundayAdefila mentioned in their comment, you can simply do:

```
event.start_at - 2.hours
```

To find events starting in the next 2 hours, you can write an `ActiveRecord` query as,

```
Event.where(start_at: Time.now..Time.now + 2.hours)
```

Even better way for the above(as suggested in the comment below):

```
Event.where(start_at: Time.now..2.hours.from_now)
```

which will be converted into an SQL query like:

```
SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE (`events`.`start_at` BETWEEN '2016-05-24 11:01:34' AND '2016-05-24 13:01:34')
```

Comment: You can also write `2.hours.from_now` which is the same as `Time.now + 2.hours`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-from_now