# tell if DateTime is within one hour of current time

Tags: ruby, datetime

My goal is to stop the loop if `dte` is within 1 hour of the current time. Is there a "ruby way" to do this?

```
#THIS IS AN INFINITE LOOP, DONT RUN THIS
dte=DateTime.strptime("2000-01-01 21:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
while(dte<(DateTime.now.to_time-1).to_datetime)
    #increments dte by one hour, not shown here
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to use the DateTime, then you are doing it the right way.

[Subtract n hours from a DateTime in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238684/subtract-n-hours-from-a-datetime-in-ruby)

You can also do:

```
require 'time'
time = Time.parse('2000-01-01 21:00:00')
while time < Time.now - 3600 do
  ...
end
```

You can be more efficient using active_support core extensions.

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/numeric/time'    
while time < Time.now - 1.hour do
  ...
end
```

Even better

```
while time < 1.hour.ago do
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Pure Ruby way (without including rails's active_support) :

You just need to take off fractions of a day.

```
one_hour_ago_time = (DateTime.now - (1.0/24))
```

- 1.0 = one day
- 1.0/24 = 1 hour
- 1.0/(24*60) = 1 minute
- 1.0/(24*60*60) = 1 second

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
current_time = DateTime.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

last_time = (DateTime.now - (1.0/24)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

last_time.upto(current_time) {|date| puts date }
```

Comment: `hour` method is not supported in ruby, it's a `Rails` method

Comment: Use `require 'active_support'` bcs. this will produce `undefined method hour for 1:Fixnum`